# How to prove the order of execution of a nested else statement?

Tags: c#, if-statement

Please note that it's **not** a question on **how *else* binds** and how the scope stretches. Also, please note, that it's not a question on if we should or shouldn't use curly braces.

Regard the following nested conditional statement.

```
if(alpha)
  if(beta)
    AlphaAndBeta();
  else
    AlphaNotBeta();
```

Personally, even if I'm a big believer of removing any redundant parenthesis, I'd suggest usage of curly braces in this case to make it abundantly clear that the *else* statement is a part of the **inner** condition, which can be tricky to see, especially if some smart-donkey starts horsing around with the indentation like so.

```
if(alpha)
  if(beta)
    AlphaAndBeta();
else
  AlphaNotBeta();
```

However, I'd like to have a handy reference to where the behavior is described. I've looked at the language definition on MSDN but haven't found the exact spot. It needs to be super-ultra-clearly stated how the *else* bind to its *if* (and doesn't necessarily have to be MS's official site).

Where can I find the page, please?

Comment: to help you visualising whats going on you could use "CodeMaid" and "Indent Guides"

Comment: @WiiMaxx Hmm... I might. Can't see however how that relates to my question. Especially given the disclaimers in the first paragraph. Am I missing your point, perhaps?

Comment: i know, because of that it is just a comment. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one resource, [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h.aspx):

> The statement or statements in the then-statement and the
>   else-statement can be of any kind, including another if statement
>   nested inside the original if statement. **In nested if statements, each
>   else clause belongs to the last if that doesn’t have a corresponding
>   else**.

Answer (score 7):

This is documented in the [C# specification, section 8.7.1 - The `if` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664746(v=vs.71).aspx):

> An `else` part is associated with the lexically nearest preceding `if` that is allowed by the syntax. Thus, an `if` statement of the form
>
> ```
> if (x) if (y) F(); else G();
> ```
>
> is equivalent to
>
> ```
> if (x) {
>    if (y) {
>       F();
>    }
>    else {
>       G();
>    }
> }
> ```

Comment: For a more explicit example +1. However, Tim's answer is even more smack-in-the-back-of-the-head, so he'll get the greeny-checky.  :)

Comment: @KonradViltersten, I believe that is a poor decision on your part. This is the clearer answer and should have been chosen as the best answer.

Comment: I can see your point and, without taking a stand, I'm not disagreeing with it. I fully appreciate the importance of accepting **the** best reply, so I wonder if his isn't stronger because it's readable even by non-developers. In your reply, it takes a few seconds to count the parentheses and figure out how the first example equates to the second. Technically, it's crystal clear and fully graspable. Isn't there, however, an advantage in reading it colloquially? I'm not arguing any case - just asking for more input.

Comment: You're entirely entitled to pick the answer that you feel best answered your question *for you*. David is also fully within his right to disagree with you. Basically, you're both right :) Don't change the accept vote unless you truly feel my answer answered the question better *for you*. Both answers answer the question, both link to official sources, albeit different sources, and both have different ways to express the same. As such, none of the answers are way better than the other. For future visitors, they can make up their own mind, which is the purpose of allowing multiple answers.

Comment: In fact, if I were to be so bold as to suggest a way to improve the answers here, I would merge my answer into Tim's, adding it to the bottom of his like "Additionally, this is also described in the more formal C# specification under section ...", and so on, and then simply deleting my answer altogether. I'll ping @TimSchmelter and see if he does it, otherwise we'll just leave it as is.